# Pegando variavel vindo do foreach

Tags: php

tou quebrando a cabeça em um problema. espero que me ajudem por favor.
Estou listando todos os registros do banco de dados. Preciso pegar o id da linha conforme o click.
Estou conseguindo apenas o ID da primeira linha, quando clico na próxima linha a variável me da o 1º registro novamente.

*Tirei todo o css e PHp desnecessário do código para ser rápido e fácil a compreensão :)

index

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Nº do Cliente</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Nome</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <?php

                                $Mostrar = new Crud();
                                foreach ($Mostrar->Listar() as $rs) {
                                    ?>


               <tr>
               <td><?php echo $rs['cli_id']; ?></td> <!--PRECISO DESSA VARIAVEL -->
                                        <td><?php echo $rs['cli_nome']; ?></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <?php include 'includes/clientes/cadastrarMoto.php'; ?> <!--AQUI FICA O MODAL PRA APRESENTAR O ID -->


                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="6">
                                            <div class="pull-left">
                                                    <span class="material-icons adicionar" title="Motos" data-balao="tooltip"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cadastrarMoto">storage</span></div> <!--CLICANDO AQUI VAI PARA UM MODAL -->




                                        </td>
                                    </tr>


                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

cadastrarMoto.php

```
<div class="modal fade">
.........
<?php echo $rs['cli_id']; ?>
```

Comment: Como assim linha?

Comment: Votei para o fechamento da sua pergunta como não clara. Não deu para entender o que você está querendo. A final de contas: o que seria "id da linha"?

Comment: Aconselho que refaça a pergunta pois esta muito confuso e se possível colocar a class 'Crud' para que possamos testar e achar a melhor solução para seu caso, Casso n queira colocar a Classe 'Crud' pesso q explique melhor a questão e que explique oque essa Classe iria fazer

Comment: Veja se este link ajuda - http://www.davidchc.com.br/video-aula/videoaula-criando-carrinho-de-compra-com-php-orientado-a-objetos-parte-1/

Comment: Obrigado por responder pessoal. desculpe se nao fui claro. https://ibb.co/dpcGUo (IMAGEM DO SISTEMA.)  https://jsfiddle.net/njfLwx83/2/ (JA COM O METODO LISTAR() ) . Espero que ficou um pouco mais claro. obrigado pessoal!

Comment: https://ibb.co/h5TRvT esta é a tela do modal. com o <?php echo $rs['cli_id']; ?>. porém ele fica fixo no COD 42. quando clico no SPAN da linha do COD 41, o echo mostra o COD 42.

Comment: tentei pegar pelo GET como parametro. mesmo assim so mostra o primeiro cli_id no loop foreach. =\

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode adicionar no valor "data" do link que abre o modal

```
<span class="material-icons adicionar" title="Motos" data-balao="tooltip"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cadastrarMoto" data-value-id="<?= $rs['cli_id']; ?>">storage</span>
```

e no modal vc pega o valor diretamente com javascript

Tem exemplos aqui
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Comment: pessoal consegui resolver. A alteração foi no span e na div do modal. segue: https://jsfiddle.net/mk5o1zrw/ . OBRIGADO! Todos os comentários foram de suma importância.